# Make Word Hyperlink to Template create New Document

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, templates

If I double click a Word template in Explorer, it opens a new document using that template. However if I create a hyperlink to a template inside a Word document, clicking the link opens the template for editing.

I would like to create a hyperlink to a template that opens a new document using the template, or a similar solution.

Comment: This [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278627) suggests linking to a shortcut of that file. It doesn't answer your question, but is the official work-around for older versions.

Comment: Nope, [others seem to agree](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/how-to-insert-a-hyperlink-in-excel-to-a-word/0a6d4725-4af1-408c-b9e2-f1c1cad6b6c7?db=5)

Comment: If there's a possible answer out there, it's going to lie in the [office uri schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx) - I think I'm beyond my depth at this point, you'd need your hyperlink to redirect to explorer.exe or cmd and then run the URI scheme. Or maybe [command line](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210565)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old method of using a hyperlink to a shortcut to the template does not work
anymore, so there is no other option than to use VBA.
I will try to walk you through the procedure.
The difference will be that to use the macro, one will need to double-click the
trigger-text, rather that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click.

1. In the View tab, click on the little arrow next to Macros and choose
   “View macros”.
2. In the windows that opens, click Create, to open Visual Basic
3. In the Insert menu, click Procedure...
4. In the dialog that opens type a meaningful name, for example “newdoc”,
   ensure that the radio-buttons of Sub and Public are checked, then click OK.
5. A text window opens on which will be three lines:

   ```vb
   Public Sub newdoc()

   End Sub
   ```
6. Paste between the above lines the following text:

   ```vb
   alpha = "Location To Your\Template Name.dotm"
   With CreateObject("word.application")
     .Documents.Add Template:=alpha, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
     .Visible = True
   End With
   Application.Quit savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
   ```
7. Click the menu File / Save normal, or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,
   followed by File / Close and Return to Microsoft Word.
8. Click in the document in the location where you want the trigger-text to be
   placed
9. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a field - the cursor will be
   placed between brackets
10. Between the field brackets, type “MacroButton”, then the name of the command
    or macro you want the button to execute followed by the text you want
    displayed, like this:

    ```
    MacroButton newdoc double-click here to create a new document
    ```
11. Press F9 to update the document. If done correctly, only the text
    “double-click here to create a new document” should now be visible.
12. Save the document.
13. Use Double-click on the text to launch the macro.

Notes:

1. The last line of the macro containing `Application.Quit`, will close the
   current document without save. If that’s not what you want, change the
   parameter to `wdSaveChanges` or `wdPromptToSaveChanges`, or omit this line
   entirely to keep the original document open.
2. The `Template` parameter in the macro should point to the dotm file, not to a
   shortcut to the dotm file.
3. There are more things you can do with a macro, like adding it to the ribbon.
   See the article [Create or run a macro](http://support.office.com/article/Create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) for more information.

Comment: Well this is certainly not ideal, but after testing it does appear to work, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If simply saving as a PDF is an option, this resolves the issue. The link is then opened as a new document based on the template.

Comment: Where in the question does it ask about saving as a PDF? If you did this intentionally, please explain why you answered this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is, to change your properties of of your template to a *read-only*, this way it the template itself will never be changed and once it is *saved as* it will be a whole new different document.

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around is to create a hyperlink to a folder that contains the template rather than the template itself.

Click n the hyperlink to open the folder, which shows the user the only template stored in that folder.

An extra click, but seems to work fine.